# Unable to load Mongodb Driver

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, nginx, php

I have a `Nnginx -FPM php server` running on Ubuntu.

I am trying to make the `MongoDB Driver` for PHP work but some how it never shows in my `phpinfo()` and every time I run a test script i get  `Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found`

The actual `MongoDB server` is not installed in that server given that I will be connecting to another server.

What am I missing that it doesnt work?

I followed this straight forward steps

1) `pecl search mongo`

Show the latest 1.4.3 (stable) verion

2) `sudo pecl install mongo`

3) `vim /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`
and at the end of the `[dba]` tag i add

```
[Mongo]
extension=mongo.so
```

4)

```
service nginx restart
service php5-fpm restart
```

[image]

Comment: Your steps to install php mongo driver are fine, You shouldn't have any problem.But if it is this problem is regarding pecl , Try to install latest Pecl .
Also show us log errors. because this sometime happens when php is unable to find mongo.so file. So remember that.

Comment: I suspect your mongo.so file got installed into the wrong directory.
In your phpinfo(), look for extension_dir and make sure the mongo.so is in that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you have mongodb.ini in /etc/php5/conf.d/ The contents should look something like:

```
extension=mongo.so
mongo.auto_reconnect = true
mongo.allow_persistent = On
mongo.max_persistent = -1
mongo.max_connections = -1
;mongo.default_host = www.example.com
mongo.default_port = 42
mongo.chunk_size = 1024
mongo.cmd = "$"
```

Comment: I added that and now i get a `mongodb.ini` inside the `Additional .ini files parsed` of the php.php but I am still not finding mongo class on test scripts or seeing it anywhere else